# sklearn pipeline and grid search

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, scikit-learn-pipeline

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
pipe4 = Pipeline([('ss', StandardScaler()), ('clf', knn)])

grid2 = GridSearchCV(pipe4, {'clf':[ knn, LogisticRegression()]})

grid2.fit(X_train, y_train)
pd.DataFrame(grid2.cv_results_).T
```

I made a knn classifier and logistic regression model and wanted to check which model is better through pipeline method.

as you can see the code above I put the knn only in the pipe4 but in grid search, both knn and logsistic regression are working and I could check the result

does it mean I can add the models in Gridseacrh even though I put the one model in pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. As long as the estimator given to the `GridSearchCV` (in your example: `pipe4`) supports the parameters passed to `param_grid` (in your example: `'clf'`), you can pass any values to the estimator's parameters in the grid search (in your example: `[knn, LogisticRegression()]`).